# Docker img.gz file

Tags: docker, centos7

I have several rpms that I have created. I would like to create a new image of Centos (7) that contains these rpms. I am just trying to get started, and I believe that I can use Docker and mkisofs to do this. The problem is, I just am not sure how to go about doing this. I realize that I have not provided what I have tried, I haven't tried anything. What I don't understand is how to move my rpm files into the image (perhaps the wrong word here) that Docker builds from centos.

I do know that my Dockerfile will need to start with:
    FROM centos:7
But what comes next? Say I have a list of packages to install (including mkisofs (probably from genisoimage).

I am having a hard time (after spending a lot of time reading docs, etc). Does anyone have any pointers to specific docs to read, or a working example that I can look at?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you have those rpms locally.

1. Place them in the same directory as your Dockerfile.
2. Use [COPY](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) commands to add those rpms in the new image
3. If you want to install them use [RUN](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run) to execute the `yum -y install` command.
4. Navigate to the Dockerfile directory and use `docker build -t <image-name> .` to build the image (the rpms should be in that directory as well).
5. Either use `docker save` to save your image to a tar.gz and share that, or `docker push` to push your image to Dockerhub so that you can share it with anyone.